# I need to know when a ISearchContext is clickable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had been searching in many places about this topic, I found a similar answer here, but I want a little more.

My code:

```
var element = myWebDriver.FindElement("User_Login");
var finalelement = element.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'OK')]"));
```

The problem it is that sometimes the button it's clicked before get available, I want to make an explicit wait for that. Right now I have these:

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static IWebElement NGFindElementWhenClickable(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"])));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));
        }

        public static IWebElement NGFindElementWhenVisible(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"])));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
        }

        public static IWebElement NGElementExist(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"])));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
        }

        public static void NGElementInvisible(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"])));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        }
```

I want to add something like this in that class:

```
public static IWebElement NGFindElement(this ISearchContext context, By by)
        {
            var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"]));            
            return wait.Until(ctx => {
                var elem = ctx.FindElement(by);
                return elem;
            });
        }
```

... but with explicit waits (conditional waits).

Comment: you have already solved the problem using the method `NGFindElementWhenClickable`, as you are waiting for the condition (to be clickable) using `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable`. Or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Naveen The method Charlie wants to add takes a SearchContext so it could either be a driver or element which doesn't work with NGFindElementWhenClickable.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, I know it's a bit late :)

Here how I did it:

```
public static IWebElement NGFindElement(this ISearchContext context, By by, int timeOut = 0)
{
        //-> If the timeOut remain the same ( = 0) use the time defined on "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"]"
        //-> on the other hand if the value is defined by the user, will use the defined value
        int totalTime = (timeOut == 0) ? int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebDriverExplicitWait"]) : timeOut;
        var wait = new DefaultWait<ISearchContext>(context);
        wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalTime);
        //-> To avaid exceptions related to page refreshed
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException));
        return wait.Until(ctx => (ctx.FindElement(by).Displayed && ctx.FindElement(by).Enabled) ? ctx.FindElement(by) : null);            
}
```